# Chromedriver is opened instead of "normal" Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, default

When I:

- Click on Ubuntu start button > type "Chrome" > Select Chrome application
- or Click on an URL on Slack

Instead of opening Chrome as it normally would, it opens the "Chromedriver" I use for my job and throws the following error:

[image]

**Translation: Error when loading extension from: . manifest file missing or unreadable**

And then it just opens "Chromedriver". There are not bookmarks and a "data:," in the URL (usually when Chromedriver starts it appears like that)

I attach two configs i have in ubuntu for default browsers. As you can see in the bash window, i have two "chromes" (I tried using both but the problem remains) and in the "Details" page instead of reading just "Google Chrome", you can see there is a page referenced "Dashboard something"

[image]

I google like a crazy person with no luck with other solution. Thanks a lot in advance